# XCUITest; how to find StatusBar

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcuitest

I am trying to create a XCUITest where I like to verify that iOS' Status Bar is either:

- hidden; or
- visible.

But I cannot 'find' it... for example:

```
func testExample() throws {

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()

    let statusBar1 = app.descendants(matching: .statusBar)
    let statusBar2 = app.statusBars.element(boundBy: 0)
}
```

When do `po statusBar1` in the console I get an empty result:

```
Find: Target Application 'com.domain.TestStatusBar'
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type StatusBar
```

Any clue of how to find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 12, the status bar is no longer accessible through `XCTest` as it is a part of the system application.
If you check in iOS 11 & below, `app.descendants(matching: .statusBar).element` should have the expected result.

In other words, you can access only those `XCUIElement`s that live within your own application window.

---

<sup>[Credits](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13764#issuecomment-617279726)<sup>*Applies to `XCTest`</sup></sup>

Answer (score 3):

It's now accessible as a springboard descendant:

```
class Springboard {

    static let shared = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

    static var statusBar: XCUIElement {
        // There are always two statusBars, 
        // but only one of them is accessible when we need to tap it
        if XCUIDevice.shared.orientation.isPortrait {
            return Springboard.shared.statusBars.firstMatch
        }
        else {
            return Springboard.shared.statusBars.element(boundBy: 1)
        }
    }
}
```